# How can I make `send` give input to Windows cmd terminal?

Tags: cmd, autohotkey

I would like to send some text to a Windows cmd terminal, so I made this simple AutoHotKey .ahk script file:

```
^!+T::Send Hello
```

However, the text "Hello" does not show in the cmd terminal windows when I press Ctrl + Alt + Shift + T, but it works fine when I use it from a simple text editor.

How can I make `send` give input to Windows cmd terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the cmd was started through a link, and for some reason this specific link did not receive the AHK send text.

I replaced the link with an new link, based on c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe, and then it works.